# Xbox One Account Transfer To PS4

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I had a Xbox One with a GTA V account on it, but now I have a PS4. Can I transfer my Xbox One account over and get it on my PS4?

Comment: @JeffS for future reference, it is considered bad form to VTC a question AND answer it. your effectivley just making it harder for the mods

Comment: @Timelord64 I'll keep that in mind for future reference. I also had a hard time finding the duplicate on mobile app so I had to switch and then flagged. Should I remove answer?

Comment: @JeffS, its entirely up to you. I am trying to find the relevant meta on it, to give you more information.

Answer (score 1):

**No, you cannot.** Both consoles are completely different platforms both in terms of physical disc copies, online community hubs and (especially) distribution services. You cannot use an Xbox account with a PlayStation as they are both entirely different.

As such, you will need to repurchase your games to accommodate the new platform.

Comment: @Lew657 If you found my post helpful, you should probably mark it as accepted by clicking the little tick mark underneath the vote arrows.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot transfer between current gen consoles on GTA V. You can only transfer from previous generations, ie. xbox 360 to ps4. If you wanted to transfer from a current generation console like Xbox One the only option would be to transfer to PC.

Straight from Rockstar Support
https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC